# How to link module with multiple tpl file?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

Is there any way to add link any module with multiple template(`.tpl`) file?

I am not sure but like this : OpenCart welcome controller file.

```
if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/welcome.tpl')){
   $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/welcome.tpl';
   $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/new.tpl';
}else{
   $this->template = 'default/template/module/welcome.tpl';}
```

But this example not working.

Comment: You want to load new.tpl content on welcome.tpl file ?

Comment: Yes and i want to call new.tpl with ajax on welcome.tpl but how? welcome.tpl just for example. @AmitMaurya

Comment: which version of opencart you are using ?

Comment: opencart 1.5.6.4 @AmitMaurya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For new.tpl, you have to create a module named **new**

Here is the way:

1. create catalog/controller/custom/new.php

   ```
   <?php  
    class ControllerCustomNew extends Controller {

    public function index() {

      if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/custom/new.tpl')) {
         $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/new.tpl';
         } else {
           $this->template = 'default/template/common/new.tpl';
         }

         $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
     }
   }
   ?>
   ```
2. create a new.tpl file under catalog/view/theme/default/template/custom/new.tpl

   ```
   <p>This is new module content</p>
   ```
3. create a custom welcome controller under create catalog/controller/custom/welcome.php

   ```
    <?php  
     class ControllerCustomWelcome extends Controller {

      public function index() {

         if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/custom/welcome.tpl')) {
           $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/custom/welcome.tpl';
         } else {
          $this->template = 'default/template/custom/welcome.tpl';
         }

        $this->children = array(
          'common/column_left',
          'common/column_right',
          'common/content_top',
          'common/content_bottom',
          'common/footer',
          'common/header',
          'custom/new'
         );

       $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
      }
     }
    ?>
   ```
4. create a welcome.tpl file under catalog/view/theme/default/template/custom/welcome.tpl

   ```
    <?php echo $header;?>
    <p>This is Welcome module content</p>
    <?php echo $new; ?> <!-- new module content -->
    <?php echo $footer; ?>
   ```
5. Load your welcome module on front-end i.e. `http://yourdomain.com/index.php?route=custom/welcome`

Comment: Thanks for help but not this. I want to connect two tpl with same module.

Comment: If you want use via ajax, url should be  
`http://yourdomain.com/index.php?route=custom/new`